# How to select same column with multiple alias name from same table?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to select values from table with following combinations

```
SELECT Details FROM  Avenger   WHERE Id = '1' AND KEY LIKE '11AX';
SELECT Details FROM  Avenger   WHERE Id = '1' AND KEY LIKE '34XA';
SELECT Details FROM  Avenger   WHERE Id = '1' and KEY = '11AZ';
SELECT Details FROM  Avenger   WHERE Id = '1' AND KEY LIKE '11ZA';
```

In single query I know that I can use

```
SELECT * FROM Avenger WHERE ID='1';
```

But I need to use all selected values and assign it to **Four Variable** in single query.

any idea or solution I can use ?

```
Id  Key Details
1   11AX    Mark 
1   34XA    Bruce 
1   11AZ    Mr. Green
1   11ZA    Hulk
2   11AX    Robert jr.
2   34XA    Toney 
2   11AZ    Iron Man
2   11ZA    Arrogant
3   11AX    Thor
3   34XA    Asgard
3   11AZ    God
3   11ZA    Hamer
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: desired  result is first four select statements,and I need to merge all those in single query

Comment: What does the "Four Variable" refer to?

Comment: Those four variables I will be using in java for displaying data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I understand you want this:

```
select 
    (SELECT Details FROM  Avenger   WHERE Id = '1' AND KEY LIKE '11AX') as var1,
    (SELECT Details FROM  Avenger   WHERE Id = '1' AND KEY LIKE '34XA') as var2,
    (SELECT Details FROM  Avenger   WHERE Id = '1' and KEY = '11AZ') as var3,
    (SELECT Details FROM  Avenger   WHERE Id = '1' AND KEY LIKE '11ZA') as var4
    from dual
```

There is also a [pivot](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot) option

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `REGEXP_LIKE` here with an alternation:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Id = '1' AND REGEXP_LIKE("KEY", '11AX|34XA|11AZ|11ZA')
```

Actually, I'm not sure you even intended to use `LIKE` in your original queries.  You might really just want to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Id = '1' "KEY" IN ('11AX', '34XA', '11AZ', '11ZA')
```

Comment: I can not accept both but this is also good answer so up vote :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `case` expression:

```
select details,
       (case when key like '11AX' then 1
             when key like '34XA' then 2
             when key like '11AZ' then 3
             when key like '11ZA' then 4
        end) as flag
from avenger a
where id = 1;
```

If you just want to select the value using a single expression, start with `in`:

```
where id = 1 and key in ('11AX', '34XA', '11AZ', '11ZA')
```

If you want to pass in the values as a single string, then `regexp_like()` works:

```
where id = 1 and regexp_like(key, '^11AX|34XA|11AZ|11ZA$')
```

Two notes:

- The pattern is anchored so it only matches complete `key`.
- `regexp_like()` generally precludes the use of an index, so for performance, `=` and `in` are better choices.

Perhaps you intend:

```
select max(case when key like '11AX' then details end) as deails_11ax,
       max(case when key like '34XA' then details end) as details_34XA,
       max(case when key like '11AZ' then details end) as details_11AZ,
       max(case when key like '11ZA' then details end) as details_11AZ
from avenger a
where id = 1;
```

This returns one row with four columns.

Comment: Thank you, This works could please help little bit more to assign this variable as alias name to any four

Comment: @v8-E . . . If the first version doesn't do what you want, I don't understand the comment.  You should edit the question and show desired results.